# Where would you add the +1 when dealing with arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, printf

Since arrays start at zero rather than one, I would like to make it clear in my code that I am adding one to the counter (i) to make up for this. However my function is not reading what I currently have.

I am rather new at coding so I apologize, but I will answer any questions;

```
do
{
    printf("\nMax # of characters?\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &x);
} while (x < 1 || x > 200);       

do
{

    printf("\nEnter Text:\n");

    enter[i] = getchar();
    i = 1;
    error = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("i = %d\n", (i - 1));
        c = getchar();
        enter[i] = c;
        i++;
    } while (c != '\n');

    if (i > (x + 1))   //<----------- Even though I added one because arrays start at [0]
    {                  //             the program still tells me 'i' (counter) is one 
                       //             more than it should be 

        printf("Words must not be longer than %d letters\n", x);

        printf("You entered %d letters\n", (i - 1)); // -1 to count for the '\n'
        error = 1;
    }

} while (error != 0);


printf("\nOutput: %s\n", enter);

return 0;
```

Comment: C uses 0 based arrays, so the code should always reflect that.  The only place you need to 'add 1' is in the UI, therefore, on the printf do I+1 & x+1.

Comment: The condition for a valid `ì` is `i < x`. You don't show the definition of your `enter` array, but you must enforce that condition while you are entering chars in order not to overflow the array. (Any there's a possibility that `i` is uninitialised when you first assign `enter[i] = c`.)

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is explicitly undefined behavior in the Standard (though supported in some implementations, this is not portable). If you are trying to clear the input stream, there are other methods available.

Comment: People usually loop into arrays or such containers with a `for`loop, which allows to declare a counter, specify when to stop looping and incrementing the counter like that `for (int i = 0;  c != '\n'; i++)`

Comment: You need to set `i` to `0` before the first getchar call.

Comment: To empty the *input buffer* (`stdin`), you can create a quick function, e.g. `void flush_stdin() { for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {} }`, then simply call it when additional characters remain in `stdin` after your call to `scanf` (or any time your accounting for all characters show the potential for unused characters remaining)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you forget to initialise `i`. The first

```
enter[i] = getchar();
```

is undefined behaviour.

Secondly, `i` is an index into the array. If `x` is the number of characters you are allowed to enter, then `i` should range between `0` and `x - 1` inclusive for the legitimate characters. You also increment `i` for the `\n`, so legally `i` is constrained by

```
0 <= i <= x
```

So your error message should be printed if `i > x` not if `i > x + 1`

---

Footnote: if you wonder why we index from zero and anybody who tells you we should index from one is wrong, then I can only point you at the definitive paper [Why Numbering Should start at Zero](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) by Edsgar Dijkstra.

Comment: (Why Numbering Should start at Zero) ... and the subtle fact that a zero-based index fits nicely with the *binary* spoken by computers as well as iteration over the number of bytes within each distinct data type, pointer arithmetic and the definition of an array, e.g. `int a[x];` where `a = &a[0] = &(*(a + 0)) = (a + 0) = a`, etc., etc. (think of how screwy the equivalence would look with `1` instead of `0` `:)`